# Linux - Command line tool to normalize a filename?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

Is there a command line tool in linux that will 'normalize' a filename? i.e. remove all "xx/./xx" parts, or "myfolder/../myotherfolder" parts?

Comment: I don't get what you are asking myself.. but could just be me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is realpath:
http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_realpath.htm

There is also a command-line version:
cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-find-real-physical-path/

But on my CentOS 5 it is not available by default.

Also there is a "cheating way":

```
$ bash -c "cd /foo/../bar/ ; pwd"
/bar
```

Comment: or just

    (cd /foo/../bar && pwd)

Answer (score 9):

`readlink -f` seems to do it (despite being intended for de-referencing symlinks):

```
[root@noldevvg19 ~]# readlink -f /etc/../usr/../etc/./sysconfig/../redhat-release 
/etc/redhat-release
```

I believe this is called 'canonicalizing'.

Comment: -f: all but the last component must exist, -e: all components must exist, -m: no requirement for existence

Comment: readlink is not guaranteed to be on a given system, that might be an issue

Answer (score 1):

Are ou asking for the  basename command ?

```
$ basename ../../.bashrc
.bashrc
```

And there is also the other part : dirname

```
$ dirname ../../.bashrc
../..
```

Comment: They are related, but they are not the answer.
One reason they aren't is that they just take one step; another is that they just rewrite the strings without looking at the file system, which may go wrong in the presence of symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

With python line command:

```
python -c 'import os; print os.path.basename("/home/mezgani/nat")'
python -c 'import os; print os.path.direname("/home/mezgani/nat")'
```